# testing facebook real time updates / user comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate realtime updates for user pages. I have a callback running on a given HOST url. Having this the subscription creation is:

```
G = facebook.GraphAPI()
app_token = config['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] + '|' + config['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
path = config['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] + '/subscriptions'
post_args = {'access_token' : app_token, 'callback_url' : HOST, 'fields' : 'feed', 'object' : 'page', 'verify_token' : 'token'}
G.request(path, post_args=post_args)
```

This seems to work just fine and a subscription is created. After this, for a given user I get oauth credentials with perms = ["publish_stream", "offline_access", "manage_pages", "publish_actions", "read_stream"]

Using this access token, I do a subscribe by adding the app to the page tabs:

```
G = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
path = "/%s/tabs" % page['id']
G.request(path, post_args={'app_id' : config['FACEBOOK_APP_ID']}
```

Now things work.... sort of. First thing is I'm not sure exactly how facebook testing should work in practice. Basically I created a bunch of test users using the app settings on developers page. Then using one of these users, I create two separate pages Page1, Page2 and I registered the app as a tab on these pages. Posts issued from the test users, or from the real user I created the app with are picked up. But I try to find one of the pages from some **other real user** (so not a test one and not the one I created the app with) and I cant. Even if I copy paste the entire URL, I just get a redirect to the first page. Are those pages only visible inside my own test app/users context ? Should I create a page from my real account and test with that? I'm just curious on how would I go around testing this in a real setup. **Would I get ALL comments / posts on that page regardless of the user who does the posting or just posts from the Page / Admins of the page ?**

Another separate problem I'm having is creating a comment from some user. So I'm using the exact same access token I've got above, and having a post from someone come it, I want to issue a reply in the form of a comment on that post. I have the facebook post id, so I just:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
graph.put_comment(facebook_post_id, message)
```

Say I issue this command using the access token I got from TestUser1 on a post that came on his own page Page1 . I would expect that the comment be posted on behalf of TestUser1 but instead it gets posted on behalf of Page1 . Is this expected as a side effect of the token I'm using? I've read here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ that there are user access tokens and page access tokens; but I've tried the exact same thing with a token without the 'manage_pages' perms and still get the same thing.

Cheers, Bogdan